# Transit all day every day

Tags: code-golf, date

In addition to contributing to Stack Overflow and other SE sites, I like to ride public transit during my free time. I'd be spending a fortune on cash fare and/or bus tickets every month if I didn't have a bus pass. But for the average passenger, how much would you need to ride to make it worthwhile to buy a pass?

### Input

Two parameters: Passenger age and transit usage report.

[Standard loopholes apply.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) You can read input from CLI arguments, function arguments, or a file (whichever works best for your language).

#### Transit usage log format

Each line represents a trip:

```
<date> <time> <route number> <start> à <destination>
<date> <time> <route number> <start> à <destination> // comments, if any
```

Date is in ISO 8601 format. Time is 24 hour format (hours and minutes, both with leading zeros). The remaining information on the line is irrelevant for this question.

#### Fare structure

Tickets are $1.60 each.

```
            Child (0-5)    Child (6-12)  Student (13-19)   Adult (20+)
Cash           Free           1.90            3.55            3.55
Tickets        Free              1               2               2
DayPass        Free           8.30            8.30            8.30
Monthly pass   Free            n/A           82.25          103.25
```

#### Transfers

When paying with cash or tickets, a transfer (proof of payment) will be provided. The validity of the transfer is calculated as follows:

- Until 04:30 the next day if time of boarding is after 22:00, else
- 105 minutes from time of boarding on weekends, else
- 90 minutes from time of boarding

If you have a valid transfer at the start of a trip, you do not have to pay anything.

For the purposes of this question, make the following assumptions:

- All routes cost the same
- You never lose your transfer or day pass
- You do **not** have a transfer from the last day of the previous month.

#### Day pass

If more than $8.30 in cash is spent in a day, a day pass is cheaper.

A day pass is valid from 03:00 to 03:00 the next day. If a day pass is purchased at 02:30, it is only good for 30 minutes!

### Output

Output may be in the form of a return value or written to STDOUT. A trailing newline is permitted.

Your program/function must output the cost of each option as follows (order does not matter):

```
C: $50.45
T: $44.1
J: $47.25
P: $100.75
```

J represents the calculation for a combination of cash with day passes where a day pass would have been cheaper.

Numbers must be truncated to at most two decimal places. Trailing zeros can be omitted.

For passengers age 6 through 12, passes are unavailable so any non-digit output for `P` is OK (whether it be false, empty string, nil, null, not a number, "Infinity", etc.)

#### Bonus

-5% if you indicate the least expensive valid option in the output by printing any printable character before method of payment. For example:

```
P: $NaN
C: $117.80
*T: $99.20
J: $117.80
```

### Test cases

#### Input transit usage log

```css
body {white-space: pre; font-family: monospace}
```

```html
2015-04-01 02:28 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-01 06:31 98 Laurier à Tunney's Pasture
2015-04-01 06:51 176X Tunney's Pasture à Merivale/Rossdale
2015-04-01 08:06 176 Merivale/Family Brown à Laurier
2015-04-01 22:16 97 Campus à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-01 22:51 95 Lincoln Fields à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-02 19:01 95 Campus à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 22:31 170 Barrhaven Centre à Fallowfield
2015-04-02 23:22 95 Fallowfield à Trim
2015-04-02 00:41 95 Trim à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 03:48 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-02 20:25 95X Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-02 20:49 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 23:58 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-04 21:26 96 Laurier à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-04 21:51 94 Lincoln Fields à Fallowfield
2015-04-04 22:10 95 Fallowfield à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-04 22:38 95 Barrhaven Centre à Hurdman
2015-04-04 23:24 95 Hurdman à Mackenzie King
2015-04-05 00:03 1 Dalhousie/York à Johnston/Bank
2015-04-05 00:43 97 Greenboro à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-06 01:41 95 Lincoln Fields à Fallowfield
2015-04-06 02:11 95 Fallowfield à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 05:21 95 Longfields à Laurier
2015-04-06 18:17 94 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-06 18:49 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Place d'Orléans
2015-04-06 00:41 95 Place d'Orléans à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 02:01 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-06 19:15 94 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-06 19:49 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 23:51 170 Strandherd à Fallowfield
2015-04-07 00:21 DH Fallowfield à Baseline
2015-04-07 00:39 95 Baseline à Laurier
2015-04-07 17:20 71 Mackenzie King à Berrigan/Edge
2015-04-07 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-09 00:40 95 Trim à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-09 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-09 16:32 41 Campus à Hurdman
2015-04-09 16:37 94 Hurdman à St. Laurent
2015-04-09 17:41 95 St. Laurent à Campus
2015-04-10 01:06 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-10 02:01 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-10 17:15 66 Campus à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-10 17:44 95 Lincoln Fields à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-10 23:38 95 Barrhaven Centre à Longfields
2015-04-11 00:05 95 Longfields à Laurier
2015-04-11 01:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-11 04:47 95 Barrhaven Centre à Fallowfield //stop engine
2015-04-11 05:17 95 Fallowfield à Laurier
2015-04-11 17:15 94 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-11 17:41 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-11 23:30 170 Barrhaven Centre à Fallowfield
2015-04-12 00:21 95 Fallowfield à Laurier
2015-04-12 17:30 98 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-12 21:25 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-12 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-13 07:01 16 Laurier/Cumberland à Tunney's Pasture
2015-04-13 07:27 176X Tunney's Pasture à Merivale/Meadowlands
2015-04-13 09:12 176 Merivale/Baseline à LeBreton
2015-04-13 09:21 96 LeBreton à Blair
2015-04-14 00:34 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-14 02:30 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-14 07:06 86C Laurier à Tunney's Pasture
2015-04-14 07:21 176 Tunney's Pasture à Merivale/Meadowlands
2015-04-14 08:54 86 Meadowlands/Merivale à Laurier
2015-04-14 18:43 97X Laurier à Hurdman
2015-04-14 18:55 95 Hurdman à St. Laurent
2015-04-14 19:23 95 St. Laurent à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-14 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Trim
2015-04-15 00:38 95 Trim à Laurier
2015-04-15 08:00 35 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-15 08:35 94 Mackenzie King à Campus
2015-04-15 22:15 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-16 02:01 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-16 21:01 95 Laurier à Woodroffe/Tallwood
2015-04-16 21:34 86 Meadowlands/Woodroffe à Meadowlands/Merivale
2015-04-16 21:56 176 Merivale/Meadowlands à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-17 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-17 11:52 96 Laurier à Bayshore
2015-04-17 13:21 96 Bayshore à Campus
2015-04-17 22:10 95X Campus à Baseline
2015-04-17 22:47 95 Baseline à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-18 02:53 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-18 20:14 86X Laurier à Hurdman
2015-04-18 20:22 94 Hurdman à St. Laurent
2015-04-18 20:44 94 St. Laurent à Fallowfield
2015-04-18 21:43 95 Fallowfield à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-19 00:58 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-19 15:16 95 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-19 16:22 94 Mackenzie King à Hurdman
2015-04-19 16:34 98 Hurdman à South Keys
2015-04-19 16:51 97 South Keys à Airport
2015-04-19 17:21 97 Airport à Laurier
2015-04-19 21:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-19 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-20 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-20 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Trim
2015-04-21 00:38 95 Trim à Laurier
2015-04-21 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-22 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-22 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-23 01:28 95 Barrhaven Centre à Woodroffe/Medhurst
2015-04-23 02:11 95 Woodroffe/Medhurst à Laurier
2015-04-23 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-23 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Trim
2015-04-24 00:38 95 Trim à Laurier
2015-04-24 23:15 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-25 00:23 95 Barrhaven Centre à Rideau St.
2015-04-25 01:44 96 Rideau St à Laurier
2015-04-25 16:58 86B Laurier à Albert/Bank
2015-04-25 17:44 87 Mackenzie King à Laurier
2015-04-26 01:25 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-27 01:04 95 Laurier à Rideau St
2015-04-27 01:31 95 Rideau St à Laurier
2015-04-27 17:25 41 Campus à Heron/Baycrest
2015-04-27 17:54 112 Baycrest/Heron à Elmvale
2015-04-27 18:30 114 Elmvale à Hurdman
2015-04-27 18:41 94 Hurdman à Laurier
2015-04-29 02:02 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-29 17:01 8 Campus à Heron
2015-04-29 17:37 118 Heron à Baseline
2015-04-29 18:01 95 Baseline à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-29 20:32 95 Barrhaven Centre à Mackenzie King
2015-04-29 21:31 2 Rideau St à Bank/Queen
2015-04-29 21:35 95 Albert/Bank à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-30 02:02 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-30 02:20 86C Campus à Mackenzie King
2015-04-30 02:44 96 Mackenzie King à Campus
2015-04-30 19:36 95 Laurier à Strandherd
```

#### Output

```
$ node --harmony golfed.js trips.txt 5 "Toddler"
P: $0.00
C: $0.00
T: $0.00
J: $0.00
$ node --harmony golfed.js trips.txt 10 "Child"
P: $NaN
C: $117.80
T: $99.20
J: $117.80
$ node --harmony golfed.js trips.txt 15 "Student"
P: $82.25
C: $220.10
T: $198.40
J: $194.20
$ node --harmony golfed.js trips.txt 61 "Adult"
P: $103.25
C: $220.10
T: $198.40
J: $194.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to kick off my own question by providing my own golfed solutions in two languages. These functions write to STDOUT.

### CoffeeScript, 438 bytes

```coffee
F=(I,a)->f=[C=T=x=A=0,1.9,K=3.55,K,0,1,2,2];J=[];I.split('\n').map((r)->W=new Date w=r[..9];(y=+w[-2..]-((h=R.getUTCHours())<3);C+=f[A=a>19&&3||a>12&&2||a>5&&1||0];T+=f[A+4]*1.6;J[y]=J[y]||0;J[y]++;x=h>21&&+W+1026e5||h<3&&+W+162e5||+R+(R.getUTCDay()%6&&54e5||63e5))if x<R=new Date r=w+'T'+r[11..15]+':00');o={P:[0,NaN,Z=82.25,Z+21][A],C:C,T:T,J:J.reduce ((p,v)->v*f[A]>8.3&&p+8.3||p+v*f[A]),0};console.log(O+': $'+$.toFixed 2)for O,$ of o
```

### JavaScript (ES6), 445 bytes

```js
F=(I,a)=>{f=[C=T=x=0,1.9,K=3.55,K,0,1,2,2],J=[];I.split('\n').map(r=>{W=new Date(w=r[s='slice'](0,10));if((R=new Date(r=w+'T'+r[s](11,16)+':00'))>x){y=+w[s](-2)-(V=(h=R.getUTCHours())<3);C+=f[A=a>19?3:a>12?2:a>5?1:0];T+=f[A+4]*1.6;J[y]=J[y]||0;J[y]++;x=h>21?+W+1026e5:V?+W+162e5:+R+(R.getUTCDay()%6?54e5:63e5)}});for($ in(o={P:[0,NaN,Z=82.25,Z+21][A],C:C,T:T,J:J.reduce((p,v)=>v*f[A]>8.3?p+8.3:p+v*f[A],0)}))console.log($+': $'+o[$].toFixed(2))}
```

### JavaScript (ES5), 474 bytes

There really wasn't much ES6 other than arrow functions.

```js
F=function(I,a){f=[C=T=x=0,1.9,K=3.55,K,0,1,2,2],J=[];I.split('\n').map(function(r){W=new Date(w=r[s='slice'](0,10));if((R=new Date(r=w+'T'+r[s](11,16)+':00'))>x){y=+w[s](-2)-(V=(h=R.getUTCHours())<3);C+=f[A=a>19?3:a>12?2:a>5?1:0];T+=f[A+4]*1.6;J[y]=J[y]||0;J[y]++;x=h>21?+W+1026e5:V?+W+162e5:+R+(R.getUTCDay()%6?54e5:63e5)}});for($ in(o={P:[0,NaN,Z=82.25,Z+21][A],C:C,T:T,J:J.reduce(function(p,v){return v*f[A]>8.3?p+8.3:p+v*f[A]},0)}))console.log($+': $'+o[$].toFixed(2))}
```

#### Demo

```js
F = function(I, a) {
  f = [C = T = x = 0, 1.9, K = 3.55, K, 0, 1, 2, 2], J = [];
  I.split('\n').map(function(r) {
    W = new Date(w = r[s = 'slice'](0, 10));
    if ((R = new Date(r = w + 'T' + r[s](11, 16) + ':00')) > x) {
      y = +w[s](-2) - (V = (h = R.getUTCHours()) < 3);
      C += f[A = a > 19 ? 3 : a > 12 ? 2 : a > 5 ? 1 : 0];
      T += f[A + 4] * 1.6;
      J[y] = J[y] || 0;
      J[y] ++;
      x = h > 21 ? +W + 1026e5 : V ? +W + 162e5 : +R + (R.getUTCDay() % 6 ? 54e5 : 63e5)
    }
  });
  for ($ in (o = {
    P: [0, NaN, Z = 82.25, Z + 21][A],
    C: C,
    T: T,
    J: J.reduce(function(p, v) {
      return v * f[A] > 8.3 ? p + 8.3 : p + v * f[A]
    }, 0)
  })) console.log($ + ': $' + o[$].toFixed(2))
}

// Demonstration stuff
console.log = function(x) {
  O.innerHTML += x + '\n'
}

F(D.innerHTML, 5);
console.log('<hr>Child');
F(D.innerHTML, 10);
console.log('<hr>Student');
F(D.innerHTML, 15);
console.log('<hr>Adult');
F(D.innerHTML, 20);
```

```html
<div id=D hidden style=display:none>
2015-04-01 02:28 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-01 06:31 98 Laurier à Tunney's Pasture
2015-04-01 06:51 176X Tunney's Pasture à Merivale/Rossdale
2015-04-01 08:06 176 Merivale/Family Brown à Laurier
2015-04-01 22:16 97 Campus à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-01 22:51 95 Lincoln Fields à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-02 19:01 95 Campus à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 22:31 170 Barrhaven Centre à Fallowfield
2015-04-02 23:22 95 Fallowfield à Trim
2015-04-02 00:41 95 Trim à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 03:48 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-02 20:25 95X Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-02 20:49 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-02 23:58 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-04 21:26 96 Laurier à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-04 21:51 94 Lincoln Fields à Fallowfield
2015-04-04 22:10 95 Fallowfield à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-04 22:38 95 Barrhaven Centre à Hurdman
2015-04-04 23:24 95 Hurdman à Mackenzie King
2015-04-05 00:03 1 Dalhousie/York à Johnston/Bank
2015-04-05 00:43 97 Greenboro à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-06 01:41 95 Lincoln Fields à Fallowfield
2015-04-06 02:11 95 Fallowfield à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 05:21 95 Longfields à Laurier
2015-04-06 18:17 94 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-06 18:49 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Place d'Orléans
2015-04-06 00:41 95 Place d'Orléans à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 02:01 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-06 19:15 94 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-06 19:49 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-06 23:51 170 Strandherd à Fallowfield
2015-04-07 00:21 DH Fallowfield à Baseline
2015-04-07 00:39 95 Baseline à Laurier
2015-04-07 17:20 71 Mackenzie King à Berrigan/Edge
2015-04-07 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-09 00:40 95 Trim à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-09 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-09 16:32 41 Campus à Hurdman
2015-04-09 16:37 94 Hurdman à St. Laurent
2015-04-09 17:41 95 St. Laurent à Campus
2015-04-10 01:06 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-10 02:01 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-10 17:15 66 Campus à Lincoln Fields
2015-04-10 17:44 95 Lincoln Fields à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-10 23:38 95 Barrhaven Centre à Longfields
2015-04-11 00:05 95 Longfields à Laurier
2015-04-11 01:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-11 04:47 95 Barrhaven Centre à Fallowfield //stop engine
2015-04-11 05:17 95 Fallowfield à Laurier
2015-04-11 17:15 94 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-11 17:41 95 Mackenzie King à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-11 23:30 170 Barrhaven Centre à Fallowfield
2015-04-12 00:21 95 Fallowfield à Laurier
2015-04-12 17:30 98 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-12 21:25 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-12 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-13 07:01 16 Laurier/Cumberland à Tunney's Pasture
2015-04-13 07:27 176X Tunney's Pasture à Merivale/Meadowlands
2015-04-13 09:12 176 Merivale/Baseline à LeBreton
2015-04-13 09:21 96 LeBreton à Blair
2015-04-14 00:34 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-14 02:30 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-14 07:06 86C Laurier à Tunney's Pasture
2015-04-14 07:21 176 Tunney's Pasture à Merivale/Meadowlands
2015-04-14 08:54 86 Meadowlands/Merivale à Laurier
2015-04-14 18:43 97X Laurier à Hurdman
2015-04-14 18:55 95 Hurdman à St. Laurent
2015-04-14 19:23 95 St. Laurent à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-14 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Trim
2015-04-15 00:38 95 Trim à Laurier
2015-04-15 08:00 35 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-15 08:35 94 Mackenzie King à Campus
2015-04-15 22:15 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-16 02:01 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-16 21:01 95 Laurier à Woodroffe/Tallwood
2015-04-16 21:34 86 Meadowlands/Woodroffe à Meadowlands/Merivale
2015-04-16 21:56 176 Merivale/Meadowlands à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-17 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-17 11:52 96 Laurier à Bayshore
2015-04-17 13:21 96 Bayshore à Campus
2015-04-17 22:10 95X Campus à Baseline
2015-04-17 22:47 95 Baseline à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-18 02:53 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-18 20:14 86X Laurier à Hurdman
2015-04-18 20:22 94 Hurdman à St. Laurent
2015-04-18 20:44 94 St. Laurent à Fallowfield
2015-04-18 21:43 95 Fallowfield à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-19 00:58 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-19 15:16 95 Laurier à Mackenzie King
2015-04-19 16:22 94 Mackenzie King à Hurdman
2015-04-19 16:34 98 Hurdman à South Keys
2015-04-19 16:51 97 South Keys à Airport
2015-04-19 17:21 97 Airport à Laurier
2015-04-19 21:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-19 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-20 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-20 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Trim
2015-04-21 00:38 95 Trim à Laurier
2015-04-21 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-22 02:00 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-22 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-23 01:28 95 Barrhaven Centre à Woodroffe/Medhurst
2015-04-23 02:11 95 Woodroffe/Medhurst à Laurier
2015-04-23 19:30 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-23 23:18 95 Barrhaven Centre à Trim
2015-04-24 00:38 95 Trim à Laurier
2015-04-24 23:15 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-25 00:23 95 Barrhaven Centre à Rideau St.
2015-04-25 01:44 96 Rideau St à Laurier
2015-04-25 16:58 86B Laurier à Albert/Bank
2015-04-25 17:44 87 Mackenzie King à Laurier
2015-04-26 01:25 95 Laurier à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-27 01:04 95 Laurier à Rideau St
2015-04-27 01:31 95 Rideau St à Laurier
2015-04-27 17:25 41 Campus à Heron/Baycrest
2015-04-27 17:54 112 Baycrest/Heron à Elmvale
2015-04-27 18:30 114 Elmvale à Hurdman
2015-04-27 18:41 94 Hurdman à Laurier
2015-04-29 02:02 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-29 17:01 8 Campus à Heron
2015-04-29 17:37 118 Heron à Baseline
2015-04-29 18:01 95 Baseline à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-29 20:32 95 Barrhaven Centre à Mackenzie King
2015-04-29 21:31 2 Rideau St à Bank/Queen
2015-04-29 21:35 95 Albert/Bank à Barrhaven Centre
2015-04-30 02:02 95 Barrhaven Centre à Laurier
2015-04-30 02:20 86C Campus à Mackenzie King
2015-04-30 02:44 96 Mackenzie King à Campus
2015-04-30 19:36 95 Laurier à Strandherd
</div>

<pre id=O></pre>
```